# How to find name of city and state in android at moment?

Tags: android

How to find name of city and state in android at moment ? I know how to find longitude and latitude but is there already any service to return name of city and state and maybe zip code if that is not too much ?

Comment: You want to find out the city (and further information about it) where the Andriod Device is currently located (via GPS)? Or do you want information about a named city?

Comment: @Lukas Knuth I have longitude and latitude at the moment and I need cityName, CountryName and zipCode

Answer (score 3):

you will need to use geocoding to get the address of given longitude and lattitude and then you will be able to get city,state,country,postalcode evrything..!!
Try this [link](http://www.krvarma.com/2010/07/geocoding-and-reverse-geocoding-in-android/) to get the understanding